# Bing Ads API Ruby Support in v9?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, bing, bing-api

Does anyone know if Bing removed Ruby support in v9 of their Ads API? It looks like this page is gone now - [Getting Started with Ruby](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj901705(v=msads.80).aspx).

I also don't see any Ruby examples past what seems to be v8.

Comment: @@Hammond have you find out the solution for your question as I'm also Stuck!!! on this...

Comment: Unfortunately they did remove support. I started to roll my own version (I think you found it on Github, but in the end we ended up going a different direction so I stopped the project)

Comment: It should have a pretty good starting point for integration though if you want to continue to expand upon it

Comment: @@Yes !!!  Hammond as I went through https://github.com/arambert/bing_ads_api But unable to authentication after providing the mentioned parameter. Please advise If I'm missing something.....

Comment: @VKatz I know this is a VERY old post but did you ever figure out how to use Ruby with Bing Ads API?

Comment: @JoshL, Yes. I was but I'm unable to recall.